# link data from another .ods file

Tags: windows, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I'm using openoffice calc and I have 2 .ods files (complete.ods and summary.ods).

I have 1 cell from summary.ods which depends on complete.ods. I managed to get the value by using this formula:

```
=DDE("soffice";"C:\complete.ods";"Data.D7")
```

the problem is, when I relocate both file to D:\, I need to rewrite the path again, which is not a problem for me. but I cannot expect all the users do the same thing, it's time consuming and troublesome.

I tried to use Google, is there any alternative way or a better way to define the path such as ~/complete.ods or just simple complete.ods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenOffice Calc `DDE` addressing relative to active document path *example*: as `=CELL("filename")` function returns something like

```
'file:///D:/test/ooo/summary.ods'#$Sheet1
```

you could get full path to currently open active document with (not predicating optimal)

```
=MID(CELL("filename");10;SEARCH("/[^/]+'#";CELL("filename"))-9)
```

and update you `=DDE` call as follows:

```
=DDE("soffice";MID(CELL("filename");10;SEARCH("/[^/]+'#";CELL("filename"))-9)&"complete.ods";"Sheet1.D7")
```

Please replace my (default) `Sheet1` sheet name with your `Data` in above `=DDE` call. Also might require some improvement for paths with spaces.

Comment: it worked! thanks. may i know what is the meaning of '10' and '-9' in the formula?

Comment: Check the description of `MID` function e.g. in the _OpenOffice Help_. `10` points to 10th position in a result of `=CELL("filename")` as it _always_ starts with next 9 characters: `'file:///`. And as `=SEARCH("/[^/]+'#";CELL("filename"))` gives position of last `/` in the same `=CELL("filename")` string, we need to add `-9` to get length of path...